# Request Data from Apache HTTP Server for CORS Header

Tags: apache, http-headers, cors, httpserver

I am trying to handle CORS errors by adding the following to my Apache HTTP Server 'httpd.conf' file (the following is just an example):

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

Instead of trying to guess what headers to allow, is there any way to tell it to accept any headers that are in the original request headers? I know I've heard that other web servers can do something like that.